# Call to undefined function getNameEC()

Tags: php, getter

> Hello, I'm new to php, can someone help me?
> The error occurs here 
>  `<?php for($i = 0; $i < count($stockageEventCompany); $i++) { ?> <h1 class = "NameEC"><?php echo $stockageEventCompany[$i].getNameEC()?></h1> <?php } ?>`

> However, I think I have correctly declared my Getter in my EventCompany class.

```
 public function getNameEC()
    {
      return $this->name;
    }
    public function setNameEC($value)
    {
      $this->name=$value;
      return $this;
    }
```

> To help you understand the context

````
for ($i = 0; $i < count($listeCategories); $i++) 
 {
    if($listeCategories[$i]['DateDebut'] != null)
    {
      $myObject = new Mission($listeCategories[$i] ['nameEventCompany'], $listeCategories[$i] ['descriptionEventCompany'], $listeCategories[$i] ['DateDebut'] , $listeCategories[$i] ['DateFin']);
      $stockageMission = array($myObject);
    }
    else
    {
      $myObject = new EventCompany($listeCategories[$i] ['nameEventCompany'], $listeCategories[$i] ['descriptionEventCompany']);
      $stockageEventCompany = array($myObject);
    }
 } ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! On SO the default language is English. Please change your post and make it available in English. You can further read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

test this?

```
<?php echo $stockageEventCompany[$i]->getNameEC();?>
```

I think $stockageEventCompany[$i] is an object. and to call object  method is this syntax

```
$obj->getToto();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to put this in my file, I solved the problem thank you.
`require_once 'EventCompany.php'; require_once 'Mission.php';`